# How to join a table with two tables by choosing another field value

Tags: mysql

I have three tables.
first table! `activity` with these fields: `id_company`, `id_act`, `type`[`blog` or `poll`]
second table! `blog` with these fields: `id` , 'body
`and third table!`poll`with these fields: 'id` , 'text`,`answer`

Now, I want fetch my info from `activity` table by join `activity` with `blog` and `poll` tables depend on `type` field.

```
activity table
-----------------------------
id_company|   id_act|   type
-----------------------------
1         |   1     |   blog
1         |   2     |   blog
2         |   3     |   blog
1         |   1     |   poll
2         |   4     |   blog
2         |   2     |   poll
3         |   5     |   blog

blog table
-------------------
id        |   body
-------------------
1         |   aaaa    
2         |   bbbb    
3         |   cccc
4         |   dddd
5         |   eeee

poll table
-----------------------------
id        |   text |   answer
-----------------------------
1         |   zzz  |   z   
2         |   xxx  |   x  
3         |   yyy  |   y
```

final output for    `id_company IN (1, 2)`     must like this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
id_company|   id_act|   type|   body|   text|   answer
-------------------------------------------------------
1         |   1     |   blog|   aaaa|   NULL|   NULL
1         |   2     |   blog|   bbbb|   NULL|   NULL
2         |   3     |   blog|   cccc|   NULL|   NULL
1         |   1     |   poll|   NULL|   zzz |   z
2         |   4     |   blog|   dddd|   NULL|   NULL
2         |   2     |   poll|   NULL|   xxx |   x
```

Please help me to write this query.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use left join with additional join condition on basis of type column from activity table

```
select 
a.id_company,
a.id_act,
a.type,
b.body,
p.text,
p.answer
from activity a 
left join blog b on(a.id_act = b.id and a.`type` = 'blog')
left join poll p on(a.id_act = p.id and a.`type` = 'poll')
where a.id_company IN (1, 2)
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/03c525/2)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I don't have a database to hand to try this but this should work :-

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT 
    activity.id_company
  , activity.id_act
  , activity.type
  , blog.body
  , poll.text
  , poll.answers
FROM 
activity
LEFT JOIN blog ON activity.id_act = blog.id
LEFT JOIN poll ON activity.id_act = poll.id 
)
WHERE id_company IN (1, 2)
```